# How to best draw attention to, and reward good answers, in "big-list" type questions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I would like to draw attention to the following question: [Book ref. request: "...starting from a mathematically amorphous problem and combining ideas from sources to produce new mathematics..."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828458/book-ref-request-starting-from-a-mathematically-amorphous-problem-and-comb)

Usually, I draw attention to a question by setting a bounty on it. However, I am not sure if doing so in this case would be fair to the many people who might respond with good answers, since it is a "big-list" type question yet only one of them may receive the reward.

Do I just set the bounty, and damn the fairness?

Comment: I think it is a good concern on how to reward good answers when we can only reward one answer with a bounty and that this question deserves a bit more attention.

Answer (score 4):

- Suppose there will be several excellent answers, but only one will win the bounty. Unfair?
- Several excellent football teams  arrived to Brazil recently. Only one will win. Unfair?

Just set the bounty.

Comment: Your comparison between bounties and World Cup (!) seems inadequate.. Maybe it is better to allow bounties distribution between a number of people who provided nice answers. The one who sets bounties can decide for the way that points are distributed among those who added answers.